# Why is an element accessible even after being removed from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

```js
window.a = {
  div1: $('#div1'),
  img1: $('#img1')
};

$(a.img1).click(function() {
  a.div1.html('<img id="img2" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg" />');
  $('#img2').click(function() {
    $(a.img1).attr('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</div>
```

When line # 9 executes i.e. `$(a.img1).attr('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg');` upon clicking the image second time, a.img1 should not exist. So, why is an HTTP request for that URL getting sent to server (notice in network tab)? I'm using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m. Don't think it is a browser bug. Also works same on Firefox 39.

Also done a fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/ismusidhu/vvmwntcd/.

Comment: you've removed the node from the DOM tree, but it still exists because `window.img1` still points at it - so it can't be garbage collected.

Comment: _"Why is an element accessible even after being removed from DOM?"_ Where is element removed from `DOM` ?

Comment: @guest271314 `a.div1.html()` should remove it. Isn't it?

Comment: @IsmailS Yes, you are correct; removed from `DOM` but still jQuery object at `window.a.img1`

Comment: if you steal the remote from your hotel room, it will still blink the light when you push the buttons, even if it won't do anything to any other TVs...

Comment: Not if you're far away. So if we take the jQuery DOM element and put it in a light-proof faraday cage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Marc B said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614265/why-is-an-element-accessible-even-after-being-removed-from-dom/32614537#comment53079414_32614265), you've removed the node from the DOM tree, but it still exists because `window.img1` still points at it (indirectly, by pointing to a jQuery object which in turn points to it) — so it can't be garbage collected. If you set `window.img1` to a different value (such as `null` or `undefined`), then the element can be garbage-collected.

Think of it this way: You start out with the image's parent element (and various siblings, but ignore that for now) pointing to it:

```
+---------------------+          +-------------------+
| (some DOM elements) |--------->|                   |
+---------------------+          |                   |
                                 | the image element |
+------+                         |                   |
| img1 |------------------------>|                   |
+------+                         +-------------------+
```

Then, when you call `html` on its ancestor, the DOM removes all of the references to that element, and you have this:

```
                                 +-------------------+
                                 |                   |
                                 |                   |
                                 | the image element |
+------+                         |                   |
| img1 |------------------------>|                   |
+------+                         +-------------------+
```

Release that last reference, and the element can be reclaimed/released.

Comment: It's a real answer, then why you put it as community wiki?

Comment: @IsmailS: CWs are real answers. I frequently tick the CW box when I see that someone has commented with (an incomplete version of) what I would answer with if the answer's going to be short. I don't care about rep, and it seems to help stave off complaints of having "stolen" their "answer" from the comments. (I don't think Marc B would complain in that way, but I've had it from others, so...)

Comment: That's your greatness sir! Anyway if somebody complains of stealing answers, it must be their fault. You have elaborated it. They haven't. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.a = {
  div1: $('#div1'),
  img1: function() {
    return $("> img[id]", this.div1)
  }
};

function toggle(e) {
  a.div1.html(/1/.test(e.target.src) 
             ? '<img id="img2" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg" />' 
             : $('<img id="img1" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />')
               .click(toggle)
  );
  
  $("#img2").on("click", function(e) {
    a.img1().attr({
        'src': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg',
        "id": "img3"
      })
      .click(toggle)
  });
}

a.img1().click(toggle);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vvmwntcd/6/

Comment: still browser made request to `https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg`. checked on network tab. Console does show `undefined` though.

Comment: @IsmailS: The only reason the console shows `undefined` is that the code outputs `a.img` instead of `a.img1`. Doing that `is` check *before* the element is removed does nothing to make it magically disappear later. If you use a [corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/vvmwntcd/4/), you see that `a.img1` is still a jQuery object (of course), and `a.img1[0]` still has a reference to the `HTMLInputElement` object (of course).

Comment: @IsmailS: The answer to your question is what Marc B said early on: It still exists because there's still a reference to it. Using a disconnected `img` to fetch images before showing them is a common technique. To make it not happen, clear `img1`.